# What's condition of cubic polynomial to represent an ellipse-like closed curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, convex-analysis

I know the condition for quadratic polynomial to be an ellipse-like closed convex curve is

$$ b^2-4ac < 0, $$

where $f(x,y) = ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f = 0.$

Then what's the same condition for cubic polynomial such as following?

\begin{equation}
f(x,y) = a_1x^3+a_2x^2y+a_3xy^2+a_4y^3+ a_5x^2+\\a_6xy+a_7y^2+a_8x+a_9y +a_{10} = 0
\end{equation}

I was guessing the condition might be that determinant of $f''(x,y)$ matrix be less than 0, but as element of $f''(x,y)$ are involving terms of $x$ and $y$, I don't think my guess is correct. Any hint would be appreciated.

Added some background below for your convenience. I was estimating egg-shape curve with cubic polynomial. And sometimes, the estimation is good. And in some cases, it's bad although the two datasets are similar. This led to my question.

[image][image]

**UPDATE** Thanks to people's effort on this question, I was able to clear my mind and decided to impose conditions from the original model (distorted quadratic curve if not rotated) I was trying to estimate. Now, I am using constrained cubic polynomial.

Comment: I'm not sure such a condition exists.  If you are asking for a cubic polynomial in two variable whose curve is bounded within some radius of the origin, this doesn't happen. Think, for example, about a line (degree one polynomial) and how unbounded all such sets of points are.

Comment: The curve of a bivariate cubic polynomial can consist of two components, one a closed loop and one "un-closed" (unbounded) component.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks for your comment. For better understanding, I added brief background. As you guessed, sometimes, cubic function works but not in the other. That led to my question.

Comment: I think you should give the actual cubic polynomial you believe "works" so we can see which graph its curve resembles.

Comment: Actually, true data graph is under the estimated curve in the first case. The second one also was estimated pretty close to data except for the extra curve.

Comment: I'm saying you will always have an unbounded component to your cubic polynomial's curve.  If you can overlook that "extra curve" in your application, then so be it.  If you are asking when a cubic polynomial has two components (rather than just one), that is something we can tackle.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, I think it's a good start to ponder on the two components in the graph anyway. I saw some cases the extra curve combined with oval as a single component though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $f(x,y)$ has an $x^3$ term. Let $y=y_L$ be large. 
Then the equation $f(x,y_L)=0$ has a solution, so there are points on the curve arbitrarily far from the origin. The same is true if $f(x,y)$ has a $y^3$ term.

Now suppose there is no $x^3$ or $y^3$ term. Then if our polynomial has degree $3$, there must be an $x^2y$ term or an $xy^2$ term or both. 
So the cubic has shape $ax^2y+bxy^2+\text{lower order terms}$, where at least one of $a$ or $b$  is non-zero. Let $y=x+t$.  Then (unless $b=-a$) our cubic gets transformed to a cubic in $x$ and $t$ with an $x^3$ term. So there are solutions with arbitrarily large $t$, and hence with $(x,y)$ arbitrarily far from the origin. The case $b=-a$ is dealt with by using $y=-x+t$.